# iOS 9: Interface builder toolbar flexible space push 2nd button outside the e frame

Tags: interface-builder, ios9, uitoolbar, iphone-6-plus

In iOS toolbar I have two buttons. We have problem when I added flexible space between button and it push the 2nd button outside the frame when I run the app on iPhone 6 plus emulator? just want to ask how to fix it and make it between app frame ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give leading and bottom constraint to logout button and give trailing and bottom constraint to print button. remove vertical space between this two button.

I hope this works for you.
Thank you.